# My webpage has a lot of unnecessary whitespaces, how do I fix this?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

[image]

I think my image is self-explanatory. Still, I will go into details. I have been having this problem recently while trying to build my webpage. I have just an absurd amount of whitespace on the right side of my webpage which is completely unnecessary for me. I tried changing the width of all the elements in my HTML and CSS file but I got no luck. I really need some help in order to get rid of the whitespace. 
Here is my HTML:

```
   <!DOCTYPE html>
<!--
To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
and open the template in the editor.
-->
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">

        <!-- jQuery library -->
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

        <!-- Popper JS -->
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.0/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
        <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Actor' rel='stylesheet'>
        <!-- Latest compiled JavaScript -->
        <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>


        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="main.css">
        <title></title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="container-fluid" style="font-family: Actor">
            <div class="row "  style="position: absolute; z-index: 999; opacity:1; box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), 0 6px 20px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.19); background-color: #FFFFFF; padding: 4px;">
                <div class="col-xs-2">
                     <img src="images/1-OrderUp!!.jpg" alt="OrderUp logo">
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-2">
                    <p class="text-style-1">OrderUp!!</p>
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-1" style="height: 100px; background: #511F18; width: 2px; margin-left: 784px;"></div>
                <div class="col-xs-2">
                    <button class="btn btn-danger btn-lg" style="width: 100px">Log in
                        <?php

                        ?>
                    </button>
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-1" style="height: 100px; background: #511F18; width: 2px;"></div>
                <div class="col-xs-2">
                    <button class="btn btn-danger btn-lg">Sign Up
                        <?php

                        ?>
                    </button>
                </div>
                 <div class="col-xs-1" style="height: 100px; background: #511F18; width: 2px;"></div>
            </div><br>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-xs-12" style="box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), 0 6px 20px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.19); width: 100%">
                    <div class="image">
                        <img src="images/home-1.jpg" style="width: 1350px;">
                        <p class="X">Welcome to OrderUp!!</p>
                        <p class="X_1"> Get food you love delivered at your doorstep!!</p>
                        <div >
                            <form class = "form-inline" class="srch_br"action="srch_location.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                                <input type="text" name="loc_srch" placeholder="Enter your location">
                                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger btn-md">Search</button>
                            </form>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Here is the CSS:

```
.btn.btn-danger.btn-lg{
    border-radius: 0;
    height: 100px;
}
.text-style-1{
    font-family:Actor;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size:55px; 
    padding-top:2px; 
    padding-left:20px;  
    color: #511F18";
}
.image { 
   position: relative;
}

.X{ 
   position: absolute;
   top: 200px; 
   left: 820px; 
   width: 100%; 
   color: #FFFFFF;
   font-size: 55px;
}
.X_1{ 
   position: absolute; 
   top: 270px;
   left:660px;  
   width: 100%; 
   color: #FFFFFF;
   font-size: 35px;
}
.srch_br{
    position: absolute;
    top:400px;
    left: 50px;
    padding: 15px;
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
}
```

Comment: 1) why setting `row`'s position to `fixed`? 2) `col-xs-*` class has been modified to not require the infix so please use `col-*` instead. You can read bootstrap documentation and take a look at their examples as well.

Comment: I updated it . I have set the position to absolute

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish by setting it to even absolute?

Comment: I was trying to male the div at the top fixed and make everything else scroll under. I got the suggestion from another stack overflow post. Also I have updated my code. Can you please recheck code to see where the fault lies?

Comment: Try using a CSS reset: https://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/

Comment: @kawnah Bootstrap 4 has a reset built in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These two lines are causing problem:

```
<p class="X">Welcome to OrderUp!!</p>
<p class="X_1"> Get food you love delivered at your doorstep!!</p>
```

The problem is in CSS.
your code:

```
 .X{ 
   position: absolute;
   top: 200px; 
   left: 820px; 
   width: 100%; 
   color: #FFFFFF;
   font-size: 55px;
}

.X_1{ 
   position: absolute; 
   top: 270px;
   left:660px;  
   width: 100%; 
   color: #FFFFFF;
   font-size: 35px;
}
```

left: 820px and left: 660px

change them to zero:

```
.X {
    position: absolute;
    top: 200px;
    left: 0px;
    width: 100%;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    font-size: 55px;
}

.X_1 {
    position: absolute;
    top: 270px;
    left: 0px;
    width: 100%;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    font-size: 35px;
}
```

Comment: I edited my question and put the new code I am using currently. Can you kindly check it and see where the problem lies.

Comment: read through it and try to make your code more dynamic. If you'll use fix values then alignment will be messed up on other devices other than your system.

Answer (score 3):

You have many issues

- class `X` and `X_1` for the popup are overlapping the viewport. Give it a left value in percentage.
- image is overlapping the viewport. Give it a width in percentage
- and your fixed position div is also overlapping.. Give it a width

```css
.btn.btn-danger.btn-lg {
  border-radius: 0;
  height: 100px;
}

.text-style-1 {
  font-family: Actor;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 55px;
  padding-top: 2px;
  padding-left: 20px;
  color: #511F18";

}

.image {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
}

.X {
  position: absolute;
  top: 200px;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  font-size: 55px;
}

.X_1 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 270px;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  font-size: 35px;
}

.srch_br {
  position: absolute;
  top: 400px;
  left: 50px;
  padding: 15px;
  background-color: #FFFFFF;
}
```

```html
<div class="container-fluid" style="font-family: Actor">
  <div class="row " style="position: absolute; z-index: 999; opacity:1; box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), 0 6px 20px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.19); background-color: #FFFFFF; padding: 4px;">
    <div class="col-xs-2">
      <img src="images/1-OrderUp!!.jpg" alt="OrderUp logo">
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-2">
      <p class="text-style-1">OrderUp!!</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-1" style="height: 100px; background: #511F18; width: 2px; margin-left: 784px;"></div>
    <div class="col-xs-2">
      <button class="btn btn-danger btn-lg" style="width: 100px">Log in
                        <?php

                        ?>
                    </button>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-1" style="height: 100px; background: #511F18; width: 2px;"></div>
    <div class="col-xs-2">
      <button class="btn btn-danger btn-lg">Sign Up
                        <?php

                        ?>
                    </button>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-1" style="height: 100px; background: #511F18; width: 2px;"></div>
  </div><br>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-12" style="box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), 0 6px 20px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.19); width: 100%">
      <div class="image">
        <img src="images/home-1.jpg" style="width: 1350px;">
        <p class="X">Welcome to OrderUp!!</p>
        <p class="X_1"> Get food you love delivered at your doorstep!!</p>
        <div>
          <form class="form-inline" class="srch_br" action="srch_location.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
            <input type="text" name="loc_srch" placeholder="Enter your location">
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger btn-md">Search</button>
          </form>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I set all the the width values in percentage, Still no luck.